# Execute a command for 3 lines at a time

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting, cat

I'm trying to run three separate processed while reading `foo.txt`

Here is the example:

```
cat foo.txt | while read line
do
echo line1
echo line2
echo line3
echo ""
done
```

The expected output is:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6

line7
line8
```

and continues like this. This is just an example. I want to execute some other commands…

Comment: Please check your formatting. Your post used code formatting all over the place. Also it'd help if you showed some real example rather than something contrived.

Comment: Please explain what you actually want to do. Do you want to split a file into groups of three lines and run a different command on the 1st 2nd and 3rd line of each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while true
do
    read line1 || break
    read line2 || break
    read line3 || break
    echo $line1
    echo $line2
    echo $line3
    echo ""
done <foo.txt
```

This produces the output:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6

line7
line8
line9
```

To program defensively, we should allow for files whose total number of lines is not a multiple of three.  In that case, to make sure that every line gets processed:

```
while true
do
    read line1 || break
    echo $line1
    read line2 || break
    echo $line2
    read line3 || break
    echo $line3
    echo ""
done <foo.txt
```

Comment: I think you should put the echo right after the read, otherwise if line1 was read and line2 not, the echo $line1 will not be executed

Comment: @EranBen-Natan Good suggestion.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '1; NR%3==0 { print "" }' foo.txt
```

Quite the same but on pure Bash:

```
NR=0
while read line; do
    echo "$line" 
    (( ++NR % 3 == 0 )) && echo
done < foo.txt
```

And I really wonder why do you need this.